# Windows CE power management with labview

Tags: windows-ce, labview

I am trying to control the backlight of a device using labview touch panel module.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?  In C++ I could call a setdevicepower() function but labview doesn't have the ability that I know of to do this.  I am interfacing with Windows CE 5.0 or 6.0.  Any help would be good.  Thanks!

Comment: LabVIEW can call any DLL function, as long as you know what DLL to call, what function and its parameters. This is the Call Library Function Node.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about Windows CE, but I'll try to reply.

In your C++ code I suspect you are using some library. Looking at [SetDevicePower on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee497782.aspx) it's coredll.lib, right ?

What you could do is to find a coredll.dll (if it exists) and then call this library from within LabVIEW (see: [How Do I Call a Dynamic Link Library (DLL) from LabVIEW?](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/DCB90714981A1F148625731E00797C33) ) . If the dll doesn't exist, you could write your own in C++.

Comment: Coredll.lib is the correct library.  However, this library is only available in the firmware (created with the board support package).  It is located in the ROM of the hardware.  It is still accessible by an application, but the application has to call it somehow.  I have looked at building my own library, but MSDN source code is more spaghetti code than i like to deal with, and I am not sure that if I do build it in 32 bit that the windows ce would allow usage of it.